# Is RewriteMod for WordPress site: site.ro -> site.com/?lang=ro possible?

Tags: redirect, domain

I'm not much of a WordPress specialist - is it possible to redirect new domain to the same site, but with `?lang=ro` query parameter so it shows the old site with selected language?

Result I want:

- site.com -> showing the site
- site.ro -> showing the in specified language and maintaining the links as they are on site.com, but while using site.ro

As @MrWhite mentioned in the comment: accessing the same site with two domains, one domain triggers language switch.

I have also option of using (via outdated plugin):

- pre-path (site.com/ro/)
- pre-domain (ro.site.com)
  but they will require additional configuration and this plugin is already outdated so I'd rather not change anything in that regard to not break anything.

Comment: It's probably possible, but it's not a WordPress question so much as a webserver config question (Apache's `.htaccess` file should be able to do this, and I imagine nginx can do it too). You should probably ask on [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Thanks! Will do that

Comment: IMO, this should be done in the CMS/WordPress, not Apache. All you are doing here is accessing the same site with two domains. And one domain triggers a language switch.

Comment: @MrWhite exactly what I'm looking for. You nailed the description much better than I did